# Coordinator Layout Overlapping Bottom Buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I am designing my XML and originally had a Coordinator Layout that was overlapping the Action ToolBar. I read around and found out taht adding the     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior attribute helps resolve this issue.

However, in my XML I am still having an issue with the Coordinator Layout overlapping the bottom buttons on the Preview screen. I know these buttons are actually on the phone itself, but I am still puzzled why the layout is extending onto these items. See the below images overlapping the bottom buttons, I don't ever recall seeing this before the introduction of the Coordinator Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.2" />

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.3">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: See the Layout overlapping the buttons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` what it basically does is it sets that layout below the `Toolbar` and puts both the layout into a ScrollView kind of thing. Since there's a `Toolbar` on top of that layout hence, that entire layout (ScrollView that is formed) is pushed down by the height of the `Toolbar`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so in other words there is no "fix," but the presentation to the user will essentially be a scrollview. I guess I could modify the height of the bottom child in the LinearLayout to prevent it from overlapping. Also, I am thinking that if I changed the top parent to a LinearLayout that would help resolve the issue as well.

Comment: @tccpg288 I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: I used the solution above and it helped resolve the issue. If you want to make a new post and add your code it may help, but at the end of the day when I ran on my phone I did not have the issue

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem solved it by adding

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

to the main parent which is mostly the android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout that host the rest.